# Use RazorEngine inside tinymce

Tags: razor, tinymce, razorengine

I'm writing an application that uses a given email template to generate multiple messages.

The e-mail parser works fine. I'm using RazorEngine to create the e-mail template.

The problem is that I need to generate a table using the following construct (a simple foreach):

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><th>Pedido</th><th>NF</th><th>Boleto</th><th>Vencimento</th><th>Valor</th></tr>
@foreach (dynamic item in Model.PagamentosEmAtraso) {
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="76">
<p align="center"><span style="font-size: small;">@item.NumeroPedido</span></p>
</td>
<td valign="top" width="60">
<p align="center"><span style="font-size: small;">@item.NumeroNotaFiscal</span></p>
</td>
<td valign="top" width="88">
<p align="center"><span style="font-size: small;">@item.NumeroBoleto</span></p>
</td>
<td valign="top" width="128">
<p align="center"><span style="font-size: small;">@item.DataVencimento.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</span></p>
</td>
<td valign="top" width="119">
<p align="center"><span style="font-size: small;">@item.ValorLiquido.ToString("C2") </span></p>
</td>
</tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

When I exit the html editor, tinymce messes up my code, "fixing" my code using like this:

```
@foreach (dynamic item in Model.PagamentosEmAtraso) {}
<table>
```

This is issue is happening on newer versions of tinymce - it used to accept this kind of markup.

Is there any viable solution to let tinymce accept a possibly broken html without trying to fix it?

My tinymce configuration is:

```
function initializeTinyMce() {
    $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
        // Location of TinyMCE script
        script_url: '/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js',

        // General options
        theme: "advanced",
        plugins:  " pa geb reak,legacyoutput,style,layer,table,save,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,preview,media,searchreplace,print,c  o nt extmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
        width: "960",
        height: "500",
        entity_encoding: "raw",


        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1:  " bo ld, italic,underline,strikethrough,sub,sup,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontse  l ec t,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2:  " cu t,c opy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insert  d at e,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,||,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        //content_css: "/Content/site.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url: "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url: "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url: "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url: "lists/media_list.js",

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values: {
            username: "Some User",
            staffid: "991234"
        }           
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 3.4 it is not possible anymore to turn off the tinymce validator using a config setting.
The html needs to be valid, but you may define what gets accepted as valid by the tinymce validator and what not. Have a closer look at the tinymce config params valid_elments and valid_children.